# How to install udt on ubuntu server 12.04

Tags: software-installation

I want to install udt on my server, normally (on desktop version) i just copy a udt folder into (/usr) directory but I want a different way of installing it on the server version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> UDT is a reliable UDP based application level data transport protocol
>   for distributed data intensive applications over wide area high-speed
>   networks. UDT uses UDP to transfer bulk data with its own reliability
>   control and congestion control mechanisms. The new protocol can
>   transfer data at a much higher speed than TCP does. UDT is also a
>   highly configurable framework that can accommodate various congestion
>   control algorithms.<sup>1</sup>

To install UDT, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install libudt-dev
```

For more information [Read On](http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-12.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/libudt-dev_4.9-2_amd64.deb.html)

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Pkgs.org](http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-12.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/libudt-dev_4.9-2_amd64.deb.html)</sup>